# import python module from another package

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a script with the following structure

```
./
    /foo
       __init__.py
    /bar
       __init__.py
    module.py
```

I want to use module.py both on foo and bar package, but i can't find a way to import it!

I can put the module inside both packages, but if I need to make any alteration I would have to do it on both.

Comment: `import module`? If `module.py`'s directory is on the path, that should work. If it's not on the path, then you couldn't have imported your packages either.

Comment: Which file is your entry point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually somewhat tricky, assuming we have structure like this:

```
├── bar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_bar.py
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_foo.py
└── something.py
```

the correct way to get objects from `something.py` in `some_foo.py` is by adding:

```
# foo/some_foo.py
from something import some_module
```

and then running some_foo from top level directory as a module, with `-m` option like so:

```
python -m foo.some_foo
```

add some print statements to `something.py` to test it, if everything goes right you should see some output from something.py after running some_foo. Remember you need to run some_foo from top level, not from foo directory.

Comment: why would you put `__init__.py` along side a possibly top-level module `something.py`? Why would you recommend `import *` in this case? Don't create the `__init__.py` file and don't use `import *` here.

Comment: `something.py` is not a package. `from something import some_module` might be misleading (technically, you could make `something.py` into a package programmatically but usually Python packages created as directories (like `foo`, `bar` in this case)).

Answer (score 0):

Put the `__init__.py` next to `module.py`.

More information http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=packages#packages

Comment: you don't need `__init__.py` file if the module is outside of any package

Answer (score 0):

If `import foo` works then `import module` should work in your case too.

If you need to use `from toplevel import foo` to import `foo` then you could use `from toplevel import module` to import `module`.

Comment: module.py:
`from foo import test`

foo\test.py:
`from . import module`

`>python module.py` - > `ImportError: cannot import name module`

No way to use `from toplevel import module` except PYTHONPATH magic?

Comment: I agree that toplevel `__init__.py` only needs for packages.

Comment: @AlexKroll: `module.py` is not inside `foo`. Why do you think `from . import module` would have worked? Use `import module` instead. Don't put info in the comment, [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22589572/edit) instead

Comment: It's not my question. But you wrote: _If you need to use from toplevel import foo to import foo then you could use from toplevel import module to import module._ And now my adjacent question is: which way to point python for import toplevel `module` from `foo\test.py` with `import from` syntax?

Comment: @AlexKroll: `foo` is toplevel in your case. It means that you should use `import module`.